# Interface extension

Tags: design, interfaces, polymorphism

Suppose that I have an input stream interface, which defines a method for reading data. I also have a seekable interface which defines a method for seeking. A natural way of defining a input file is then to implement both input stream and seekable.

I want to construct a data decoder from the input stream interface so I can read data from a file or from another stream. The problem is that I also want to implement seek functionality to the data decoder, since I want to be able to step individual records not raw bytes. This is not possible if I only provide an input stream, which does not have the bytewise seek method.

Should I skip the seekable interface and add the seek method to input stream instead and force all streams to at least leave it as a nop.

EDIT: The decoder does not need to seek if the client does not request a seek operation. Also the stream is associated with the decoder and cannot be changed after initialization

Comment: think of client code that is expected to use the API you are designing (or better yet, create unit tests to see yourself how it will work). How would it handle `nop`s for streams that don't support `seek`? If you find it easy and convenient, go for `nop` option; otherwise, drop this idea

Comment: @gnat letting the method return false if seeking is not supported can work very well. I can just probe for seek support using foo.seek(0,SEEK_CURRENT) ie seek 0 bytes from current position.

Comment: _"can work very well"_ - you better double check assumptions like that. I for one have seen it work pretty well in one kind context and being major headache in another. I found it _really_ safer to learn about how my API will be used with unit tests, this helps to lower uncertainty in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

The way the .NET guys solved this problem was to introduce a property `IsSeekable` that allow to know if a `Stream` can be seeked. If not and you call `Seek()` anyway, it throws an exception. It's not very polymorphic but it's simple and works reasonably well in practice. It allows Stream to be passed around freely and each method can optimise for seeking if it want. The downside is that any method that want to use `Seek()` need to check the property before.

A more object oriented approach would be to create the interface `SeekableInputStream` that derives from both `Seekable` and `InputStream`. That way a class that needs to seek like your data adapter can require that specific interface and be guaranteed that seek will work. Better yet, the compiler will warn you if you try to send an invalid `InputStream` to such method. Other method can accept any class that implements `InputStream`, including those that implement `SeekableInputStream`. The downside to this method is that if you pass your `SeekableInputStream` around a lot then once its downcasted to `InputStream` the information about its seekability is lost and you need to cast it to `SeekableInputStream` back again if you really to optimise when you can seek.

Comment: An advantage of the `IsSeekable` approach is that it reduces the need for typecasting in cases where a method can *benefit* from certain abilities without *requiring* them.  It also makes it possible for wrapper objects to expose abilities that the wrapped objects may or may not support as abilities which the wrapper may or may not support, without having to define separate wrappers types for objects that have the abilities in question and for objects which do not.  Having a type for things which are *known* to be seekable is helpful, but having methods *exist*...

Comment: ...even if they're not *known* to be supported makes it possible to use abilities in cases where they exist, even if they may not always exist.  For example, if a collection interface had a `CanGetCountQuickly` property, it might initially return `false` for a lazily-generated collection, but change to `true` after the collection had been completely read through once.  If the ability to count were an attribute of the collection type, such enhancing of abilities would not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of problem can be easily fixed by [decorating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) the object.
In your case, you're going to have your streams, using your stream interface, and a seeker stream decorator, which adds the seeking functionality you require. You can then decorate your streams with the seeking functionality whenever needed.

Comment: It seems somewhat overkill